# feed xpath import html iterate

Tags: feeds

I want to scrape a news sites with Feeds Xpath Parser. The news site is very basic, it has 10 ~ 15 titles, and below those titles a little block of text.

How can I loop through all the titles and blocks of text and have nodes created? Also it has to check every 30 mins for new articles, and if there are it should add them.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

//W